# How can I create a hit effect by changing the alpha value of material of GameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, game-development, renderer

I was making a runner game in Unity and was implementing the interaction when the player collided with a static obstacle. I want to make the character fade back and forth for 2 seconds after the collision and lose some health. To do this after the collision I am calling this coroutine:

```
void ChangeAlphaValue(float alpha)
    {
        Color newCol = material.color;
        newCol.a = alpha;
        material.color = newCol;
    }

IEnumerator TemporaryColliderInactive()
    {
        ChangeAlphaValue(0.9f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ChangeAlphaValue(0.8f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ChangeAlphaValue(0.7f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ChangeAlphaValue(0.6f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ChangeAlphaValue(0.5f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ChangeAlphaValue(0.6f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ChangeAlphaValue(0.7f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ChangeAlphaValue(0.8f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ChangeAlphaValue(0.9f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        ChangeAlphaValue(1.0f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
```

It is pretty dumb but it is not the case. The problem is the alpha value is only changed when the rendering mode of the material is transparent and when it is, the character does not fade away but only be transparent.

[image: Character Transparent]

How can I make the effect by material or in any way?

**SOLVED**

The solution I find is the 2nd alternative in this [article](https://owlcation.com/stem/How-to-fade-out-a-GameObject-in-Unity#:%7E:text=To%20fade%20a%203D%20GameObject,CutOut%20or%20Fade%20for%20now.) .

Comment: Consider using a simple time-based interpolation function instead of coroutines as the latter if used incorrectly is akin to `Application.DoEvents`.  Additionally it teaches bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job.

Comment: Well, alpha is responsible for transparency, so no wonders it works only in transparent mode. Fading is a process of object being more transparent. What result do you expect exactly. Perhaps lowering color intensity/brightness will do the job of your 'fade' without transparency?

Comment: @bartol44 When the rendering mode of material is on 'fade', changing the alpha value from inspector does exactly what I looking for. I am trying to do the same effect from script.  How can I lower the color intensity from script?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, in question you stated, that rendering mode is the problem and that is becoming 'transparent' not 'fading', while in the comment you say that's what you were looking for. I probably don't understand something :P Doesn't the piece of code you provided achieve just that? It is a script, and it's changing alpha value. Regarding color intensity, I'm not expert on that. You would need to tweak your color values. Empirically, if you are in color palette, colors to the right are more intense, colors to the up are brighter.

Comment: @MickyD as SO doesn't allow opinionated questions and there are no PMs, would you care joining SO chat on unity channel? One answer you provided to me once isn't enough, and it seems pretty important, as you remind everyone about not using co-routines.

Comment: The transparency is rendered by the shader, you can't make the effect unless wrtting your own shader.

Comment: @MickyD IMO your analogy is wrong because this is **Unity-specific coroutine**, (You must return a YieldInstruction in each iteration). It's different from iterator/enumerator in general C#.

Comment: @bartol44 Unity chat? Sure.

Comment: @shingo I'm not talking about the _requirements_ of Unity coroutines but rather a) there are easier and safer ways to do things b) their misuse of C#'s `IEnumerator` and `yield`.

Comment: @MickyD https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248144/unity3d